# Finding two points from an univariate function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm quite puzzled by the following problem.

**Problem**

Let

$f\left(a,b\right)=\int _a^b\:\left(2-x-x^2\right)dx$

Find $a$ and $b$ such that $a\le b$ and $f(a,b)$ is local maximum.

My doubts came by the form of

$\int _a^b\:\left(2-x-x^2\right)dx$

it's a single variable integral, and $f(a,b)$ it's for a multivariate.

and for that reason I'm extremely sure that the first dumbest thing that came through my brain was looking

$\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx,\:a\le b$

and maximizing $f(x)$ but I'm entirely sure that that's the wrong step to take, so I'm puzzled for the notation and want the problem asks.

If someone could explain to me the nature of the problem it would be fantastic.

Comment: Well, to begin with, the function $f$ is not defined.

Comment: Is $f : (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \int_a^b (2-x-x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: Do you have the following result available to you?  Let $D = \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial b^2} - \left[\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a\text{ }\partial b}\right]^2$. Then if $D(c, d) > 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a^2}(c, d) < 0$, there is a relative maximum at $(c, d)$.

Comment: The second partial derivative test, right? yes it did not came through my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $ c\in(a,b)$.
$$
f(a,b) =\int_a^b(2-x-x^2) dx$$
$$=\int_a^cg(x)dx+\int_c^bg(x)dx$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}=-g(a)=a^2+a-2$$

Comment: Si si, il peut calculer les dérivées partielles sans avoir calculé l'integrale comme dans la reponse ci-dessus.

Comment: Ok now I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

$f\left(a,b\right)=\int _a^b\:\left(2-x-x^2\right)dx$

$f\left(a,b\right)=\big [2x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3 \big ]^b_a$

$f\left(a,b\right)=\frac {12b-12a-3b^2+3a^2-2b^3+2a^3}{6}$

$\frac {\partial f}{\partial a}=\frac{-12+6a+6a^2}{6}$

Maximum  means $\frac {\partial f}{\partial a}=0 \Rightarrow -12+6a+6a^2=0$

$(a-1)(a+2)=0 \Rightarrow a=-2$ or $a=1$

Similarly get $b=-2$ or $b=1$

Since $a<b$ must be $a=-2, b=1$

etc...

Comment: (+1) Although, there are some things I disagree with: maximum does not _mean_ $\frac {\partial f}{\partial a}=0$. You made a mistake, $a^2+a-2 = (a-1)(a-2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Define
$$ f(x,y)=\int_y^x(2-t-t^2)\,dt=G(x)-G(y) $$

Then $f_x(x,y)=G^\prime(x)=2-x-x^2=-(x+2)(x-1)=0$ and

$f_y(x,y)=-G^\prime(y)=-2+y+y^2=(y+2)(y-1)=0$ and

$f_{xx}=-1-2x,\,f_{yy}=1+2y,\,f_{xx}=f_{yy}=0$ so $D(x,y)=-(1+2x)(1+2y)$

Since $D(1,1)=D(-2,-2)=-9<0$ $f$ has saddle points there.

But $D(-2,1)=9$ and $f_{x,x}(-2,1)=3>0$, $f$ has a local minimum there.

And, since $D(1,-2)=9$ and $f_{xx}(1,-2)=-3<0$, then $f$ has a local maximum there.

Thus, $f(1,-2)=\int_{-2}^1(2-t-t^2)\,dx=4.5$ is the value at the local maximum.
[image]